# What type of aircraft is depicted in the Taylor Swift music video "Look What You Made Me Do"?

Tags: aircraft-identification

It looks like some sort of business jet or small regional airliner, but I can't tell anything more specific than that.  About the only thing I'm certain about is that it's a T-tailed twinjet with rear-mounted engines.

View of the starboard side of the aircraft in question:

[image: a starboard-side view of the mystery aircraft]

Frontal view of the aircraft's empennage:
[image: the mystery aircraft's tail, viewed from the front]

Apologies for the poor lighting and resolution (especially in the first image).

Comment: Look what you made me do. You made me watch a Taylor Swift video!

Comment: @TomMcW And yet you Swiftly returned, likely without Taylored clothing.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

According to [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/TaylorSwift/comments/6wzc13/cutting_the_wings_off_the_plane_in_lwymmd/), it is a Gulfstream G650 with the wings cut off, from a Taylor Swift music video [“Look what you made me do”](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3tmd-ClpJxA).

It has 8 windows like a G650, but is not a real aircraft.

1. the engine fans don’t look right
2. the wing leading edge has non-flush rivets and there are too many of them
3. the window size, shape, and spacing are wrong
4. there is no front entry door

And no one would be crazy enough to actually cut the wings off a 65 million dollar aircraft.

I don't think it is CGI because of how poorly some of the details are rendered. CGI should be more accurate.

It’s probably a Hollywood prop left over from some movie.

[image: music video - looking towards tail]
[image: Gulfstream G650 - looking towards tail]
[image: Gulfstream G650 - looking towards tail]
[image: music video - looking towards cockpit]
[image: Gulfstream G650 - side view]
[image: music video - side view, cutting the wings off]
[image: music video - front view, cutting the wings off]
[image: music video - front view, cutting the wings off]

Comment: What do you mean when you say the engine fans don't look right?

Comment: @Cloud Feed something like "jet engine intake" to your favorite image search engine. Those blades look at least to me like they would *block* the air rather than draw it in, by virtue of the almost nonexistent spacing, which would mean that the engines could never function.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: I thought he was referring to the fact that the fanblades on the real G650 are scimitar- or boomerang-shaped, whereas the fanblades on the "Look What You Made Me Do" G650 are completely straight.

Comment: What's wrong with the leading edge?  I can't see any difference between the real G650 and the LWYMMD G650 in that regard.

Comment: @Sean Possibly. I'd think some clarification from Mike in that regard would be welcome.

Comment: One more thing - trying to do that to the wing of a real G650 would flood the hangar with flaming Jet A.

Comment: My guess is it's a damaged airframe scheduled to be cut up for scrap. In which case there would be no engines in the nacelles, so the set people would have to make fake fan blades to put in the hole. That would explain odd-looking straight blades instead of scimitar

Comment: @TomMcW it could be camera angle/perspective but the tips of the wings in the video appear bent up a lot more sharply than in pictures of G650s, based on that I'd assume it's entirely a prop/mockup not a damaged airframe.

Comment: @DanNeely: It looks to me like perspective would probably be enough to account for the difference in winglet angle, but a) we don't get a very good look at the winglets (the camera is focussed on Taylor, who is standing fairly close to the wing root, and the lighting, as I noted earlier, is not exactly the best) and b) I still agree with you that it's most likely a prop or mockup of some sort.

Comment: Ah, now I see the issue re: the rivets.

Answer (score 12):

That appears to be a CGI rendering of a jet based upon a Gulfstream G-V or G550.  It appears to have its wings or wingtips clipped off.

[image]

Comment: @VladimirF despite this probably not being a rendering, that's not a good reason: you can "dance" and do lots of other stuff on renderings, ask on movie.SE

Comment: She’s dancing on a green screen rig; the airplane is added digitally in post production.  The record company is NOT going to destroy a $68 million airplane, no matter how much Taylor Swift complains about that

Comment: it's utterly commonplace to "dance on" a CGI rendering - for 15? years now.  it's completely trivial to do that.

Comment: "A lot is technically possible, but very expensive" you are 30 years out of date, it's completely trivial now, @VladimirF

Comment: @CarloFelicione: compositing two real shots with green-screen is not the same thing as CGI.  There's almost certainly a real plane that someone pointed a camera at, not just a fully CGI rendering of a computer model.  I like [@TomMcW's guess](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/50388/what-type-of-aircraft-is-depicted-in-the-taylor-swift-music-video-look-what-you#comment131429_50390) that it's a damaged airframe that would otherwise be scrap, repurposed as a movie prop.

Comment: One may dance on a real aircraft (BTW there is no close up, so it may be a stunt double), then "cut off wings" digitally. Alternatively, they could have used a written off aircraft. Or even a plane under construction.

Comment: @VladimirF The chainsaw scene looks really wrong, and doing it on a model seems dangerous, even with a stunt double. CGI is the only sane way to do that.

Comment: @Fattie having done some video editing and computer rendering, I can assure you that CGI with human interaction, changing lighting, and photorealistic reflections is far from *trivial*; though it is much more accessible than even 10 years ago. The official 'behind the scenes' videos show lots of green screen, but never in any scene with the airplane. After watching the airplane scenes at 1/4 speed and checking for rendering artifacts or anything 'too perfect', I'm fairly sure this was a physical model. *Could've* been rendered, but cheaper and faster to get this level of quality with a prop.

Comment: hey @brichins - i work in the business.  cheap as chips.  {particularly compared to the general high cost of a major video for an A-list star}  (Note that, thought I like T. Swift as much as the next guy, I haven't seen the clip, and don't care how it was done!  :) )  Note that merely Joe Khan's fee would totally crush a few dollars for CG.

Comment: Whater, lets delete it, its off topic anyway. I resign. I looked on the photos before only because it is not the kind of music I would like to hear.

Comment: @Fattie FWIW, dancing on a rendering is much older than that, https://youtu.be/IFGdlSbJAUE?t=3m28s long before the rendering was done by computer.